# Correct way to deal with SVN an Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I have on my SVN this folders:
- branches
- tag
- trunk

I was wondering. Should i upload the whole project folder to trunk, for example, or should i upload each of the files of the project?

It is much more simple to make just a commit over the project folder at Eclipse, but i'm not sure what's the best way to work with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you want to begin tracking an existing project with SVN.

The first step, I would say, is figuring out which folders and files shouldn't be tracked by SVN (typically all of the build artifacts, like binaries, documentation and generally speaking everything that can be regenerated at will) and ignoring them by setting the `svn:ignore` property, which I'm pretty sure you can do with subclipse (but I'm not familiar with it, so don't quote me on this).

Once you are done setting up your ignore list, you can commit the whole project in one go.
Committing on a per-file basis has absolutely no practical use.

The only precaution I can think of applies if you are a stats junkie: if you are going to use a tool such as [statsvn](http://statsvn.org/), the name under which you do the first commit will stand out as the developer with most changed/added lines. So using a fake name for the first commit might make sense in that case.

**Edit**

**Repository structure**

SVN users generally tend to have one huge repo that will contain every project; that's rarely the right thing to do, though.

YMMV, but it's often much better to stick to the per-project repository rule. It has the added bonus of making the transition towards a DVCS such as git or Mercurial much more straightforward, should you ever choose to do so in the future.

So, to answer your comment, I wouldn't bother creating `MyProject` under trunk if possible. Just stick all its contents straight in trunk.

Comment: I will only have one project for this SVN repository. Ok, so i will upload just the project folder. More simple :)
THanks.